# ionic3 toggle label in separate line

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using ionic toggle, and below is the simple code:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>test</ion-label>
  <ion-toggle checked="true"></ion-toggle>
</ion-item>
```

Now, label and toggle are in one line, I want the label and toggle both open a new line with 100% width, how can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just put them outside the `ion-item` like this:

```
<div>
 <ion-label>test</ion-label>
 <ion-toggle checked="true"></ion-toggle>
</div>
```